# SQL joins 3 tables and then pull data from 4th table in single query

Tags: mysql, sql

My database is MySQL. I have 4 tables, here is the structure:

```
users
---------------------------------
id | user_name | email | password
---------------------------------

tools
-----------------------------
id | tool_name | tool_details
-----------------------------

package
----------------------------------------------
id | package_name | tool_id | price | validity
----------------------------------------------

transaction
-----------------------------------------------
id | user_id | package_id | buy_date | expire_date
-----------------------------------------------
```

Now, I have users.id as an input using which I want to know which user is using what package of which tool. The output should be something like this

```
user_name | tool_name | tool_details | package_name | price | buy_date | expire_date
```

I have run this query but using this I don't know how to get tool_name

```
SELECT 
  users.user_name, 
  transaction.package_id, 
  transaction.buy_date, 
  transaction.expiry_date
  package.price 
FROM 
  transaction 
  INNER JOIN 
    users ON 
    users.id = transaction.user_id 
  INNER JOIN 
    plans ON 
    transaction.package_id = package.id
```

Comment: From `package` (in your query incorrectly named `plans`), you got an `tool_id`. Use that in the same way you joined the other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add another join to bring in the columns from your tools table

```
SELECT 
  users.user_name, 
  transaction.package_id, 
  transaction.buy_date, 
  transaction.expiry_date,
  package.price,
  tools.tool_name 
FROM 
  transaction 
  INNER JOIN 
    users ON 
    users.id = transaction.user_id 
  INNER JOIN 
    package ON 
    transaction.package_id = package.id
  INNER JOIN
    tools ON
    package.tool_id = tools.id
```